# Store the value of GraphicsAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width - c# Monogame

Tags: c#, types, monogame

When I try to store the width of the screen the following way:
`private int screenWidth = mGraphicsAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width`
I get the error: "field initializer cannot refer to the non static field or non static methode "Game1.mGraphicsAdapter" "
but the return type of mGraphicsAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width is supposed to be int, according to the documentation.
The GraphicsAdapter is initialized as
`private GraphicsAdapter mGraphicsAdapter = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter;`

I only started with C# recently, so please pardon me if that's only a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a variable with a non const value.

Replace the lines with:

```
private int screenWidth;
private int screenHeight;
private GraphicsAdapter mGraphicsAdapter;
```

Then in the `protected override void Initialize()` method of the Game1.cs file:

```
mGraphicsAdapter = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
screenWidth = mGraphicsAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
```

Please note that by using the adapters directly, the result is the first screen detected, which may or may not correspond to the screen the game is running on, and disregards any windowing.

A better way is to use the game window as currently utilized in the game:

```
screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;
```

`screenWidth = mGraphicsAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!
If Im getting you right, 

`screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;`

returns the current screen size when placed inside the Update function; so it's the best solution to respond to changing screen sizes (eg full screen mode).